# Get rid of the backslash from a goose extracted text

Tags: python, regex, goose

I have a small regex problems with text extracted by goose.

I have extracted the clean text out of a html page using Goose, the output that goose gives is fine, but with a small problem. I get the below string.

```
    My name is Sam\'s, I like to play \'football\'

The actual text looks like 

    My name is Sam's, I like to play 'football'

I am trying to get rid of the backslash. When I try the below code for the text extracted by goose, somehow the code doesn't work, however, if I input the text myself the code works perfectly.

I tried the below code

re.sub(r"\\","",text) or
text.replace("\\","")
text.decode()
```

Please find the code below:

```
from goose import Goose
url = 'http://economictimes.indiatimes.com/news/politics-and-    nation/swach-bharat-drives-draws-inspiration-from-mahatma-    gandhi/articleshow/49203355.cms'
g = Goose()
article = g.extract(url=url)
text=article.cleaned_text

print text
.....International School here on Friday, Gandhi\'s 146th birth anniversary.Gurjit Singh said that apart from Gandhi\'s birth anniversary,....

text=re.sub(r"\\","",text)
print text
.....International School here on Friday, Gandhi\'s 146th birth anniversary.Gurjit Singh said that apart from Gandhi\'s birth anniversary,....
```

How do I get rid of the backslash.

Comment: `re.sub(r"\\","",text)` should work fine.

Comment: [`text.replace('\\','')` works](https://ideone.com/zzE3nN). Please show all relevant code you have.

Comment: Hi stribizhev, I have mentioned the code in the post.

Comment: It is really strange as the page does not contain any literal backslashes in the text you posted, and thus they should be missing in your output. No idea what is wrong.

Comment: try text=re.sub(r"\","",text) .. I know you are supposed to use the literal feature - but I've seen weirder ... Also, thats the first time I've run accross IDEONE - nice find @stribizhev